# access JSON object returned from GET request

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, meteor, get

*This question has changed form my earlier one as developed from it.*

**How do I access the JSON object that is returned when I make the GET request.** This is reference to the line of code that reads `console.log('SUCCESS ' + result);` below. The log in the server read `SUCCESS [object Object]`

**In addition, is the code a valid asynchronous function?**

The general sequence of authorisation is...  POST request > I saved data from response > made GET request > JSON object returned > (now want to access this data).

I put the get request inside the if / else statement. So if the first request (POST) is successful, the next request (GET) will be made

```
     Meteor.methods({
      getToken: function (authCode) {
      var queryParams = qs.stringify({grant_type: 'authorization_code', code: authCode, redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/profile/', client_id: '87hjHJEBKD9J', client_secret: '8GIMSONNJ9d'});

//start POST request
  var result = HTTP.call("POST", "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?",
      {query: queryParams, data: "json"},
      function (error, result) {
      if (result.statusCode != 200) {
      console.log('post request failed');
      }
      console.log(result.data.access_token);
      var accessToken = result.data.access_token;
      var queryParamsOauth = qs.stringify({oauth2_access_token: accessToken});
//end POST request

//start GET request
      var result = HTTP.call("GET", "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,summary)?",
      {headers: { 'x-li-format': 'json' }, query: queryParamsOauth},
      function (error, result) {
      if (result.statusCode != 200) {
      console.log('FAILED' + error);
      }
      console.log('SUCCESS ' + result);
      });
 //end Get request
      });
      }
  });
```

The get request is step.4 from https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Doc that states JSON object is available https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/api-requests-json

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the client logged in via LinkedIn, try finding an appropriate package.

A quick `meteor search linkedin` comes up with `jonperl:accounts-linkedin`, `pauli:accounts-linkedin`, and `yefim:accounts-linkedin`. The most recent appears to be by pauli:
https://github.com/PauliBuccini/meteor-accounts-linkedin/

Comment: Im not using their plugin for users to to log into my app. I am trying make the POST request with a variable. I will edit my question as linkedin is not really significant to the question, but to understand the method of making a HTTP POST request with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the Meteor HTTP package? I haven't used it myself, but it looks like it can do what you are wanting to do.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http

Comment: I am aware of this but its the url that I need to construct. The url is determined by a variable that needs to be passed as a query parameter. The variable I called  'authCode.' The value of this variable is the 'code' parameter  contained in the url immediately after a user authorises my app access to their linkedin data.

Comment: okay making progress...please see my server.js code. I have passed the 'authCode' variable to server and constructed the full query parameters. This needs to append to host name and make the complete url.